infeasible inequalities using S-lemma
Let
$ f(x) = x^T A x + 2a^T x + a_0,\quad g(x) = x^T B x + 2b^T x + b_0.$ Then there exists $x^*$ such that $g(x^*)<0$, the system
\begin{array}{l}
f(x) < 0 \\
g(x) \leq 0
\end{array}
is infeasible if and only if  $\lambda \geq 0$ such that $f(x)+\lambda g(x) \geq 0$
So here is an example
Find the characteristic expression for the infeasibility of the system
$x^2+y^2-2xy+y+\alpha \leq 0$ and $-x^2+y+4xy+\beta <0$.
but how can i check the $f(x)+\lambda g(x) \geq 0$?? can i use the positive semidefinite matrix and replace the condition by $M_1+\lambda M_2 \geq 0$ where $M_1, M_2$ are positive semidefinite matrices of $f(x), g(x)$
i'm still an student can u explain for me?
